# Is there a WIX option to automatically create error table with error strings

Tags: wix, windows-installer

It seems like the error codes numbered 1000 to 1999 below are ship errors and must be authored into the Error table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-error-messages

Is there a WIX option to create Error table in the msi with all these ship errors. Wanted to avoid copying every msi error into our project to create the error table.

Tried seeing if there is an option in WIX to automatically create error table, could not find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localized strings are available in WixUI. You can reference them using

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/wixui/#using-translated-error-and-progress-text